# Why is dotnet not reading my request body correctly?

Tags: c#, json, .net, rest

I have a ForumController where I have a function ChangeOrder with a ChangeOrderDto. Here is the code:

```cs
[HttpPost("change-order")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeOrder([FromBody] ChangeOrderDto[] forums)
{
    foreach (var dto in forums)
    {
        var forum = await context.Forums.FindAsync(dto.Id);

        if (forum is not null)
        {
            forum.Order = dto.Order;
            forum.ParentId = dto.ParentId;
        }
    }

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok();
}
```

```cs
public class ChangeOrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

However when I post to /api/forum/change-order with json

```json
{
  "forums": [
    {id: 3, order: 1, parent_id: 1},
    {id: 4, order: 2, parent_id: 1}
  ]
}
```

I get this error in response:
Validation failed, forums field is required.

I tried adding [FromBody("forums")] but it did not work.

Comment: Well for one thing, that's not valid JSON - it doesn't have quotes round the properties. For another thing, I'd expect the *whole* body to be the parameter - so it would start with a `[` and end with `]` given that the parameter is an array.

Comment: Like Jon Skeet said, you're expecting an array, but you're providing a mal-formatted, invalid JSON which has a field that's holding an array. You need to fix the JSON and remove the "forums" field from it, so that the JSON represents an array instead of an object with an array.

Comment: omg its not malformatted, i just wrote it fast

Comment: Sorry, I meant mal-formed. I wasn't talking about the formatting of the text representation, I meant that the JSON is not well-formed, it's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, your JSON should look like this:

```json
[
    {"id": 3, "order": 1, "parent_id": 1},
    {"id": 4, "order": 2, "parent_id": 1}
]
```

You may need to change `"parent_id"` to `"parentId"` as well since you don't specify any custom property name for the JSON parser.

It then would look like this (also formatted for legibility):

```json
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "order": 1,
        "parentId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "order": 2,
        "parentId": 1
    }
]
```

If you want to validate your JSON, you can also use a service like this one: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

Extrapolating on the answers from below your post (Jon Skeet and ewerspej), lets build this payload:

First, You want to send an array of data:

```json
[

]
```

This array have in your case 2 objects:

```json
[
  {

  },
  {

  }
]
```

Objects you transferring have some properties with values:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "order": 1,
    "parentId": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "order": 2,
    "parentId": 1
  }
]
```

Take a look especially at the name of `parrentId` property - I think this should be named like this in the payload instead of `parent_id` that You used in your payload.

Comment: its not the problem, my problem is that dotnet complains: forums field is required.

Comment: Yes, and both answers deal with that. You need to remove the "forums" field from your JSON and only pass an array instead of an object with an array.

Comment: Correct - payload presented in both answers is the complete payload to be sent - nothing more. No additional braces, no additional names etc.

Comment: and it is without the "forums" field. i changed it. still getting same erorr

Comment: Please share the request you are sending in your post - let's say a screen from postmant showing full request with configuration.

Comment: i fixed it, had to restart the server, now it works. thanks guys!